# Every 3-regular graph without cut edges has a perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to understand Petersen's Theorem as a corollary to Tutte's Theorem.

Corollary 5.4.  Every 3-regular graph without cut edges has a
perfect matching.

Proof. Let $G$ be a 3-regular graph without cut edges, and let $S$
be a proper subset of $V$. Denote by $G_1, G_2, \dots, G_n$ the odd
components of $G - S$ and let $m_i$ be the number of edges with one
end in $G_i$ and one end in $S, 1 \leq i \leq n.$ Since $G$ is
3-regular
\begin{align}
        \sum_{v \in G_i} d(v) &= 3 |(G_i)|, \tag{5.8}
\end{align}
for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and
\begin{align}
        \sum_{v \in S} d(v) &= 3 |S|. \tag{5.9}
\end{align}

By equation (5.8), $m_i = \sum_{v \in G_i} d(v) - 2 \epsilon(G_i)$ is odd, where $\epsilon(G_i)$ is the number of edges in $G_i$. Now $m(i) \neq 1$ since $G$ has no cut edges.  Thus $m_i \geq 3$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.  It follows that

\begin{align}
   o(G - S) = n \leq 1/3 \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \leq 1/3 \sum_{v \in S} d(v) = |S|
\end{align}

Therefore by Tutte's Theorem, G has a perfect matching.

Question.  I can see that $m_i$ as given by the expression $\sum_{v \in G_i} d(v) - 2 \epsilon(G_i)$ is odd whenever $G_i$ is an odd component.  (I can also see that $m_i$ is even whenever $G_i$ is even.  I can prove both facts.  But I can't see how the equation $m_i = \sum_{v \in G_i} d(v) - 2 \epsilon(G_i)$ was deduced from equation 5.8.

I know that $\sum d(v) = 2 \epsilon(G_i)$.  That's theorem 1.1 in the book.  (The sum of the degrees of a graph equals 2 times its number of edges.  A very intuitive theorem.)  But I can't connect this fact and equation 5.8 to give the expression for $m_i$.  Any direction is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is not that Petersen theorem. You need Tutte theorem to prove it, no?

Comment: That's correct.  This is a corollary to Tutte's theorem.  I'd invoke Tutte's very soon.  But I didn't understand that expression for $m_i$ yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we take the sum $$\sum_{v \in G_i} d(v)$$ (keeping in mind that $d(v)$ is $v$'s degree in $G$, not in $G_i$) then every edge with *two* endpoints in $G_i$ is counted twice, and every edge with *one* endpoint in $G_i$ is counted only once.

- There are $\epsilon(G_i)$ edges with two endpoints in $G_i$, so they contribute $2\epsilon(G_i)$ to the value of the sum.
- The edges with one endpoint in $G_i$ are precisely the edges between $G_i$ and $S$ (there are, by definition, no edges between $G_i$ and $G_j$ for $i \ne j$) so they contribute $m_i$ to the sum.

So we get $$3|G_i| = \sum_{v \in G_i} d(v) = 2 \epsilon(G_i)+ m_i$$ and then you know what to do from there.

---

Later on, we need the inequality
$$3|S| = \sum_{v \in S} d(v) \ge \sum_{i=1}^n m_i$$
which follows for similar reasons. In the sum of $d(v)$ over all $v \in S$, there are three types of edges to consider:

- Edges internal to $S$, which would be counted twice, but which we just throw away in the inequality.
- Edges going from $S$ to $G_i$ for some $i$ of which there are exactly $m_i$; 
  each is counted in the sum once.
- Edges going from $S$ to some even component of $G - S$, which we also throw away.

Comment: I'm now at the last step.  I can't see why $o(G - S) = n <= 1/3 \sum m(i).$ (I'll add the rest of the proof to the question.)

Comment: Simply because $m_i \ge 3$ for all $i$, so $\sum_{i=1}^n m_i \ge 3n$. (We rule out $m_i = 1$ because $G_i$ has no cut edges, we rule out $m_i = 2$ because $m_i$ is odd, so we must have $m_i \ge 3$.)